# micro-sd-card will not stay in. How can I rectify

Tags: hardware, sd-card

The micro-sd-card will not stay in by Pi. It is pushed out by the spring. I think that the latch must be broken.

**Is there a way to fix it, so that the SD-card stays in?**

Model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1

Comment: it won't be pretty, but you can loop a long  cable tie around the RPi so that it keeps the SD card from backing out

Comment: @jsotola can you make that an answer. I hope for a better one, but if not then I will try it. If it works, then I will wish to up-vote.

Comment: that is a hack, not an answer .... a rubber band would also work ....    did you check your SD card for damage?